# JPEG image 'onload' fires too late

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, firefox, image-loading

On Chrome (48, 50) and FF (44) there seems to be a delay between when an image is rendered and when the `onload` event is fired.

This is particularly noticeable when throttling the connection. So I assume it's related to that but I don't know why it happens.

I've uploaded a video here: https://youtu.be/Bbbdd-pcuD4 and made the code available at: http://jsbin.com/fuloja but the relevant parts are just:

```
const i = new Image();
i.onload = () => alert('onload fired');
i.src = newUrl;
```

Do you know why this happens? It seems to occur with JPEG only as far as I can tell

Comment: I'm thinking it could be related to the image format (I tried with progressive and baseline jpegs with the same results) but bitmaps seem to trigger immediately

Comment: Are you sure the image is COMPLETELY rendered? Browsers start rendering images the moment there's enough data to render part of the image. The onload will trigger only after the image have finished downloading. Try with small jpegs (1k or less - about the size of a single TCP packet)

Comment: You are right, with a 1kb image triggers immediately (I've added one on the fiddle). I guess I wasn't expecting baseline JPEGs to need more data after the first full pass.